# Post URL from multiple <select> elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have a page with isotope filter. It's using the combination filters with hash history. So whenever multiple filters are selected it updates the URL like this:

```
example.com/portfolio/#.filter1&.filter4&.filter6
```

Then I have a search form with multiple 'select' elements:

```
<form id="search-form" method="post">
<select>
  <option value="filter1">Filter Name</option>
  <option value="filter2">Filter Name</option>
  <option value="filter3">Filter Name</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="filter4">Filter Name</option>
  <option value="filter5">Filter Name</option>
  <option value="filter6">Filter Name</option>
</select>
 ...
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

I would like to combine the values from all the selected options of each 'select' element into the single URL and redirect to isotope ('portfolio') page with that combined value.

What would be the best way to achieve that? I'm unable to figure it out.

Comment: try to use: [Arg.js](https://github.com/stretchr/arg.js/tree/master)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your js:

```
var data = { 'filters' : arrayHere };

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'your url here',
  data: data,
  success: function(re) {
   console.log('this is your return', re);
  }
 })
```

Make an array using $.each, and populate all values inside the array, then post it view ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

1) Keep the selects out of the form and use IDs to access the selected values.

2) Create a hidden input field in the form

3) use onsubmit="mergeSelects()" javascript event.

4) create a function in js

```
function mergeSelects(){
   //get all the values of selects
   // append then and generate a string may be
   var mergedStringVal = ""; // <--- store values here
   // Set it in the hidden input field created in the form and submit them
   document.getElementById("mergedSelects").val(mergedStringVal);
}
```